# Need help optimizing Mutation observer for array of node lists

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I'm new to the MutationObserver API but I tried using it for the following:

I have a node which I need to hide once it's loaded and I'm getting to the node by observing for node additions until an .innerText or property is matched.

The issue is the element I have to observe gives me an array of 4 node lists. The node list to be hidden is [1]. I got the following code to work but it's not very elegant I would say. In the Chrome dev console I'm getting a bunge of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined` errors and I'm pretty sure way more elements get observed then necessary, about 200 whereas the node to be hidden is the second one retrieved.

Here's the MutationObserver code. I'd appreciate it if you helped to improve it:

```
// Callback function to run when changes are observed
function callback(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (mutation.addedNodes[0].innerText.includes('Documents')) {
            console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0].innerText);
            mutation.addedNodes[0].style.display = 'none';  // Desired note is hidden in the DOM (end result)
        }
    });
}

// Elements to be observed
const node = document.querySelectorAll("div[class^='ControlZone-control']");  // Gives 4 node lists

// Create new instance, pass it callback function, then call .observe() and pass it node to be observed with options
for (let i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
    const observerInstance = new MutationObserver(callback).observe(node[i], {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to check the type of mutation before executing code that only works for "added nodes" mutations.

Comment: The problem is that not all mutations are about added nodes, some may be about removed nodes so you need to check addedNodes.length P.S. @connexo, the OP observes just one type (childList) so no need for that check.

Comment: Checking for addedNodes.length helped minimize errors thx. Can you help me with terminating the loop that creates the observer objects, though? As I mentioned 4 are looped through and after [1] I don't need to create more observer objects. I can't get my head around how to break this loop.